# How to add dictionary to SQL server table?

Tags: c#, list, entity-framework, dictionary

I have an SQL table in my database that stored the currency rate of a specific currency.
I want to insert bulk all the dictionary data that I'm collected from the URL.

Using entity-framework I create automatically entity class of table:

```
public partial class tblCurrencyRates
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CURRENCYCODE { get; set; }
    public string RATE { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LAST_UPDATE { get; set; }
}
```

This is my function that taking all history data rates of specific currency:

```
public static void downloadFileByTypeCurrencyAndDateRange()
{
        string curr = "01"; // for usd dollar

        DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2005");
        DateTime endDate = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        XmlReader reader = null;
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CURRENCIES));

        Dictionary<DateTime, Dictionary<string, CURRENCY>> dict = new Dictionary<DateTime, Dictionary<string, CURRENCY>>();

        for (DateTime date = startDate; date <= endDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
        {
            string url = string.Format("{0}?rdate={1}{2}{3}&curr={4}", URL, date.Year, date.Month.ToString("d2"), date.Day.ToString("d2"),curr);
            reader = XmlReader.Create(url);
            CURRENCIES currencies = (CURRENCIES)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

            Dictionary<string, CURRENCY> tempDict = currencies.CURRENCY
                .GroupBy(x => x.CURRENCYCODE, y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            if(tempDict.Count!=0)
                dict.Add(date, tempDict);   
        }
 }
```

Also, I have this help classes but I'm not sure if I need them:

```
    public class CURRENCIES
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public List<CURRENCY> CURRENCY { get; set; }

        public string LAST_UPDATE { get; set; }
    }
    public class CURRENCY
    {
        public string CURRENCYCODE { get; set; }     
        public string RATE { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to create list of tblCurrencyRates and add range to my table but how I can convert a dictionary to my **tblCurrencyRates** list?